# how to loop employee attendance using array_search to get current employees number of days attedance from data object

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, mpdf, time-and-attendance

Here is my data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstname": "Amol",
      "lastname": "Auti",
      "emp_primary": "1",
      "emp_id": "1001",
      "company_name": "Maverick Solution",
      "id": "1",
      "in_time": "09:00:00",
      "out_time": "16:00:00",
      "total_time": "07:00:00.000000",
      "date": "2018-08-04",
      "device_id": "12:12:12:12"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Amol",
      "lastname": "Auti",
      "emp_primary": "1",
      "emp_id": "1001",
      "company_name": "Maverick Solution",
      "id": "18",
      "in_time": "09:00:00",
      "out_time": "16:00:00",
      "total_time": "07:00:00.000000",
      "date": "2018-08-05",
      "device_id": "12:12:12:12"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Amol",
      "lastname": "Auti",
      "emp_primary": "1",
      "emp_id": "1001",
      "company_name": "Maverick Solution",
      "id": "5",
      "in_time": "09:00:00",
      "out_time": "12:00:00",
      "total_time": "03:00:00.000000",
      "date": "2018-08-06",
      "device_id": "12:12:12:12"
    },
    {
      "firstname": "Sumit",
      "lastname": "Malusare",
      "emp_primary": "2",
      "emp_id": "1002",
      "company_name": "Maverick Solution",
      "id": "20",
      "in_time": "09:00:00",
      "out_time": "18:00:00",
      "total_time": "09:00:00.000000",
      "date": "2018-08-05",
      "device_id": "12:12:12:12"
    }
  ]
}
```

where emp_primary = 1 have 3 records and emp_primary 2 have 1 record

And here is my actual problem

```
public function getdaterange($start, $end, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $start  = new DateTime($start);
    $end    = new DateTime($end);
    $invert = $start > $end;
    $dates = array();
       $dates[] = $start->format($format);
         while ($start != $end) {
            $start->modify(($invert ? '-' : '+') . '1 day');
            $dates[] = $start->format($format);
            }
            return $dates;
    }

public function export(){
  $getdateRangeVal = $this->getdaterange($from, $to);   
        foreach ($_data as $value) {
          $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary] = $value;
            for($i = 0; $i<count($getdateRangeVal); $i++){
            $key = array_search($getdateRangeVal[$i], array_column($_data, 'date')); 
                if(strlen($key) > 0) {
                    $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary]->dateRange[] = array(
                        "status" => "P",
                        "getdateRangeVal" => $getdateRangeVal[$i],
                        "intime" => $_data[$key]->in_time,
                        "outtime" => $_data[$key]->out_time,
                        "totaltime" => $_data[$key]->total_time,
                    );`enter code here`
                } else {
                    $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary]->dateRange[] = array(
                        "status"=>"A",
                        "getdateRangeVal"=>$getdateRangeVal[$i],
                        "intime" => "",
                    "outtime" => "",
                    "totaltime" => "",
                    );
                }
         }
    }
  }
```

and this is result of this program

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Amol
            [lastname] => Auti
            [emp_primary] => 1
            [emp_id] => 1001
            [company_name] => Maverick Solution
            [id] => 5
            [in_time] => 09:00:00
            [out_time] => 12:00:00
            [total_time] => 03:00:00.000000
            [date] => 2018-08-06
            [device_id] => 12:12:12:12
            [dateRange] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-01
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-02
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-03
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-04
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-05
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-06
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 12:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 03:00:00.000000
                        )
                )
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [firstname] => Sumit
            [lastname] => Malusare
            [emp_primary] => 2
            [emp_id] => 1002
            [company_name] => Maverick Solution
            [id] => 20
            [in_time] => 09:00:00
            [out_time] => 18:00:00
            [total_time] => 09:00:00.000000
            [date] => 2018-08-05
            [device_id] => 12:12:12:12
            [dateRange] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-01
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-02
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => A
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-03
                            [intime] => 
                            [outtime] => 
                            [totaltime] => 
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-04
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-05
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 16:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 07:00:00.000000
                        )
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [status] => P
                            [getdateRangeVal] => 2018-08-06
                            [intime] => 09:00:00
                            [outtime] => 12:00:00
                            [totaltime] => 03:00:00.000000
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

look at data i have to add 3 records to emp_primary 1 or array[1] and 1 record to second array but first emp record is assigned to another all record
please help me.

Comment: can you elaborate your question.
means you want all the records based on emp_primary in $arrstatus

Comment: Right sir i want to get all records of 1st employee in one array and in second array i want to get all records of another employee from data array

Comment: But now my program return first employee record in second and third employee array

Answer (score 0):

changed your function.

```
public function export(){
  $getdateRangeVal = $this->getdaterange($from, $to);   
        foreach ($_data as $value) {
          $valToStore = $value;
          for($i = 0; $i<count($getdateRangeVal); $i++){
            $key = array_search($getdateRangeVal[$i], array_column($_data, 'date')); 
            if(strlen($key) > 0) {
              $valToStore->dateRange[] = array(
                "status" => "P",
                "getdateRangeVal" => $getdateRangeVal[$i],
                "intime" => $_data[$key]->in_time,
                "outtime" => $_data[$key]->out_time,
                "totaltime" => $_data[$key]->total_time,
              );
            } else {
              $valToStore->dateRange[] = array(
                "status"=>"A",
                "getdateRangeVal"=>$getdateRangeVal[$i],
                "intime" => "",
                "outtime" => "",
                "totaltime" => "",
              );
            }
         }
         $arrstatus[$value->emp_primary][] = $valToStore;
    }
  }
```

try once.

Comment: Failed brother i got repeat arrays

Comment: repeated array. can you send me a code to run somewhere like PHPFiddle so i can run it and check.

Comment: hey brother i can share my remote desktop i have wested 14-15 days on this code but i dont get any result

Comment: yeah no problem bro